# Entity returns rows only sometimes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

So I have a entity query that's calling just a raw sql string and it works when I run it for one company, i get the rows I want.  But when I run it for multiple companies with the same scheduled start time, they all return zero rows.

```
using (var context = new AMWebEntities2())
{
    var joinedUpp = await context.Database.SqlQuery<PocoTest>(sql,
         new SqlParameter("site", id), new SqlParameter("ids", inValues))
         .ToListAsync();
    var final = joinedUpp.GroupBy(c => new {c.InventoryID, c.ClientID});
    foreach (var variable in final)
    {
         finalGroupedData.Add(variable.FirstOrDefault());
    }
    return finalGroupedData.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible it's not completed the query?  If you're running multiple queries or the same query multiple times in one call, maybe it isn't done yet?

Comment: @DylanWright So i need to go ahead and wait for the result?

Comment: Maybe, I see you're using await, so is your call async?  If so and your query is large you've moved on in your code and it will return once it is finished.  I would run your query see how long it runs in SQL (database).  Then match that call in your code.  If it takes 2 minutes to run wait 2 minutes.  Set some breakpoints, etc.  make sure your query is executing and completing.

Comment: @DylanWright I ended up taking out my async and it still has the same issues and when I did a log and placed the query in sql server, I got the results in about 10 seconds.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you I'd need to see the data and have the code to step throw.  It could be one of many tthings

Comment: I ended up fixing the problem, but it was such a memory hog that I had to say screw it and only allow one at a time.  I'm going to go back to it this weekend and see if I can optimize it further and make it work out